# It is ok to store fixed data in server nodejs without database?

Tags: node.js, database, store

i want to store data users that are initialed in server nodejs, this data won't change. I dont know is it reliable?

Comment: its depends to many thing like security , and other thing , you could save json in file in your code

Comment: so this way makes it less secure than saving it in database?

Comment: you could encrypt and then save to file , and when your server starts decrypt the file

Comment: is it good if i initial this data with global instance,  i am newbie in nodejs. thank you

Comment: how many size of your initial data , you could use config file or env file

Comment: i store about 50 records, i think i will use config file. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `config` https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

or use `ini` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini